# Magnetic force on a wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Where does the force of magnetic field that is created by current is exerted ? in the positive charge atoms of the wire ?

Answer (score 0):

The force of the magnetic field is exerted on the moving charges that are responsible for creating the magnetic field in the first place.

[image]

Magnetic fields are created by moving charged particles (or current)...so you could either say that the force is exerted on the charged particles or the current (interchangeably in this case).

Comment: how is it possible the source of field to exert a force in itself ?

Comment: We know that the magnetic force is F=qv x B... giving us the magnitude of our force. The right hand rule gives us the direction that the force is acting on the charge.  When we are dealing with a current carrying wire, the force is said to be acting on the wire— which is really composed of these moving charges. We can only have a magnetic force acting on a charged particle when there is relative motion between the charged particle and the field (so the charged particle moving through the field or the field moving around the wire)!  The field isn’t exerting a force on itself.

Comment: You have a field, and you have a charged particle. The inclusion of relative motion between them creates the force. Imagine the right hand rule where your index finger is the direction of charge motion, and the middle finger is the direction of the magnetic field... we have our resultant force direction acting in the thumb direction. Imagine that if the charge is moving left and the force is pointing up... we have the force acting from under the charge pushing upward acting on the moving charges.

Comment: but electrons create the magnetic field so how is it possible a charge to exert a force to itself ?

Comment: Any moving charged particle can produce an electric field. Not only electrons— though electrons are most significant. Moving particle + magnetic field = magnetic force.  Where’re the force decides to act is back on the charge. It doesn’t affect the production of the force.